# Como seleccionar un input radio dentro de un div

Tags: html, jquery

tengo un código JS que cuando selecciono uno de los 2 input radio de un form me devuelve si es correcta o incorrecta la pregunta. Necesito por favor saber como seleccionar el radio le pinche donde le pinche en el div ya que cuando le doy click al div tan solo me cambia el color pero no me deja el radio seleccionado.

El código es el siguiente

JS:

```
$("#listado li ul li div").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class')=='correcto seleccionado'){            /*si acierta*/
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('acertado_usuario');
            $(this).siblings('.normal').removeClass().addClass('resto');
        }
        else if($(this).attr('class') == 'normal seleccionado') {       /*si no acierta*/
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('fallado');
            $(this).siblings('.normal').removeClass().addClass('resto');
            $(this).siblings('.correcto').removeClass().addClass('acertado');
        }
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');                         
        $(this).siblings().css('cursor', 'default');              

        correctas = $('.acertado_usuario').size();
        falladas = $('.fallado').size();
        no_answer = $('.correcto').size();
        nota = ((correctas - (falladas /(4-1)))/total) * 10;
        nota4 = ((correctas / total) - (falladas /(4 * total))) * 10;

        $("#resultado_a").html("Correctas: "+correctas);
        $("#resultado_b").html("Incorrectas: "+falladas);
        $("#resultado_c").html("Sin respuesta: "+no_answer);
        $("#resultado_d").html("Nota: "+nota.toFixed(2));
    });
```

Y el form contiene los siguientes radios:

```
<div class="correcto"><input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?></div>
<div class="normal"><input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?></div>
```

Comment: deberías utilizar el método hasClass('yourClass') en lugar de la comprobación a través del attr ya que estas constantemente cambiando las clases y podria generar error.

Comment: Perfecto!!! y si quisiera ocultar el radio? es decir que en el DIV solo me aparezca el texto del input...

Comment: yo dejaría los input type radio como ocultos y mediante javascript al pulsar sobre el div accionas el input, al estar oculto no se vería pero al mandar el formulario si que te saldria como marcado.

Comment: Si les pongo a los input radio style="display:none" no selecciona, es decir, cuando al final hago el POST no la cuenta...

Comment: has probado style="visibility: hidden" ? también tienes que accionar la pulsacion del radio cuando se pulse el div

Comment: @David, nada, es que me pierdo porque no sé exáctamente la sentencia que tengo que poner en mi JS... no te preocupes, voy a ver si encuentro algún ejemplo parecido porque por mas que toco el JS no hace nada :(

Comment: Te recomiendo que te mires una guía de JQuery, es una librería para javascript que facilita mucho el trabajo y es muy facil de usar. Aquí tienes un tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#correcto').click(function(){
  $('#chkCorrecto').click();
});

$('#normal').click(function(){
  $('#chkNormal').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
<div id="correcto">Correcto</div>
<div id="normal">Normal</div>
<input type="radio" name="chkComprobacion" id="chkCorrecto" value="correcto" style="visibility: hidden;">
<input type="radio" name="chkComprobacion" id="chkNormal" value="normal" style="visibility: hidden;">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

prueba esto a ver si se envía el formulario con el check correspondiente

Comment: Tampoco funciona David. De todas formas no puedo alterar el id, name y value del input ya que de ello depende luego el POST que hago al enviar el form.

Comment: eso no importa, para el javascript solo necesitas añadirle un id o una clase para poder referenciarlos, el resto lo puedes dejar como lo tenias

Answer (score 0):

Si pongo este código fuera del JS que puse arriba sí que selecciona el radio, pero sigue apareciendo el boton de radio.

```
$('.correcto').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true)    
    });
$('.normal').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true)    
});
```

Creo que lo que busco es hacer algo como esto:

```
$(".normal :radio").hide().click(function(e)
```

Comment: Este código de alguna manera me gustaria integrarlo en mi JS, por eso el mareo.